# What are multi-stage pastry molds called?

Tags: equipment, dessert, pastry

Like many amateur pastry chefs I love watching Amaury Guichon.

There is a tool that he and other pastry chefs use very frequently that I'm completely unable to find. One clear example is his famous coconut: https://fb.watch/2IjsP0vpox/

You can see as he makes the core of the coconut he uses a series of spherical molds with different materials to form the center. I don't care particularly much about the spherical piece, but my mind is entranced with the idea of multi-stage molds.

Unfortunately it appears that these devices are impossible to google for or find. What are these progressive molds called? Are these publicly available or something special that Amaury made for himself?

Answer (score 3):

There’s nothing special about the mods, they are just various kinds of spherical molds.

I am quite sure that the different materials has to do with different use cases (some have to be oven proof, others not), but probably more with what manufacturer offered which diameter. If the chef is aiming for a specific layer thickness, they’ll have to find the corresponding sizes, and just go with whatever material they are made of.

Looking at my collection of kitchen tools, I have over time amassed round cookie cutters in different diameters, materials and heights, and will just grab what size I need for the given project. I would assume the same is true for the spherical molds here.

More details, as you insist that I must be mistaken, here a list of similar products (no endorsement or claim that these are the same):

First step (baked center) could be something like [this](https://www.amazon.de/gp/aw/d/B07PDYFRK5/)

Various diameter molds (with holes, as you emphasized) for example [here](https://www.deco-relief.com/silicone-mold-sphere-4-cm.html) in silicone, I am sure there will be other models in other materials.

Comment: I'd suggest you watch the whole video, because that's very much not true. They are very different from traditional molds. Not only do they all lock together in precise ways, but they have special outlets cut into them to allow for this kind of nesting.

Comment: I did watch it. Spherical molds come in different versions, with (e.g. for handling overflow, the kind used in the later steps) or without holes (e.g. for making hollow chocolate balls).

Comment: Is there a way to search for a mold like that? A polycarb insert into a silicone base with an outlet? Whether or not it's accessible outside of a set I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @SlaterVictoroff is there a reason you need exactly such a mold type? don't the more traditional silicone-only or polycarbonate-only work for you? BTW, if you have the money to spend on a trial, you could get a silicone half-sphere mold and non-attached polycarbonate sphere molds of the same size and see if they fit well enough to use them like in the video.

Answer (score 1):

I am a French pastry chef; those are Silikomart molds.